Two different facebook feeds but only 1 works while the other give error Error: Unowned Facebook Pages are not supported
I have some strange behavior displaying a facebook page.
If I want to display a feed for Whistler Blackcomb, I use the below code and is displays perfectly:
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/whistlerblackcomb/" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="" data-height="" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true">
    <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/whistlerblackcomb/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/whistlerblackcomb/">Whistler Blackcomb</a>
    </blockquote>
</div>

I want to display the feed for Hiraya Ski Resort but I get an error as follows:
Error: Unowned Facebook Pages are not supported.

The code I use is as follows;
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/平谷高原スキー場/166400960115958" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="" data-height="" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true">
    <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/pages/平谷高原スキー場/166400960115958" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/平谷高原スキー場/166400960115958">Whistler Blackcomb</a>
    </blockquote>
</div>

The page is viewable if you copy and paste the link though.
ultimately, I have a few hundred resorts with facebook pages and I want to use PHP to substitute the links but I cannot get it working even if I manually change for now like above.

Apparently you can't embed "unofficial" pages. This isn't a page created and operated by this ski resort, this is just a page Facebook has created because people have shown interest in the place.

Thank you and did not know that.  I could not find the error message documented anywhere.  If you have to have a link, would be very happy to receive.  Again, thank you.

No, I don't have any link to where this would be documented. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin only says all "public pages" could be embedded, but that doesn't appear to be the case - that second page from your question appears to be public. But if you take the error message, and what the tooltip on the page has to say, together, then this is the only conclusion that makes sense, IMHO.
